# Nested Listview, Buttons inside event handler not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, button, nested

I have hunted all over the web to try a similar circumstance and couldn't, please help me this thing has been driving me insane.

Ok what I am trying to do is have nested ListView and buttons inside these and the code behind cannot see the buttons being clicked inside the nested listview for example. I have many listview groups which need to stay. If I do 1 listview parent (button can be seen and works). Its when parent -> child -> child (here buttons cant be seen) this is where the problems occur.

All the data is all correct and listview groupings all work its just that damn button.

Some Of the ASP Code apologies in advance for the indentation.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvSOLGrpDelAdd" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="plcSOLGrpAdd">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table class="tblDespPackSOL">
        <tr class="tblDespPackSOLH">
        <td>O/N/L</td>       
        <td>Qty</td>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Description 1</td>
        <td>Description 2</td>
        <td>Unit Cost</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>Qty Desp</td>
        <td>Allocate</td>
    </tr>

    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcSOLGrpAdd" runat="server" />
</table>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<tr class="tblDespPackSOLAdd">
   <td colspan="9"><%# Eval("Name") %>, <%# Eval("A1")%>, <%# Eval("A2")%>, <%# Eval("TownCity")%>, <%# Eval("CountyState")%>,<%# Eval("Country")%>, <%# Eval("PostCodeZip")%></td>
</tr>

<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvSOLGrpDelMeth" OnItemDataBound="lvSOLGrpDelMeth_RowDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>

<tr class="tblDespPackSOLDelMeth">
    <td colspan="9">DELIVERY METHOD -->> <%# Eval("DescDelivMethod") %></td>
</tr>
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvSOL" DataKeyNames="SalesOrderLine" OnItemDataBound="lvSOL_RowDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr id="trSOL" runat="server" class="tblDespPackSOLNorm">
        <td>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSOL" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("SalesOrderLine") %>' />
<%# Eval("SalesOrderLine") %></td>
<td><%# Eval("Qty") %></td>
<td><%# Eval("Code") %></td>
<td><%# Eval("Desc1") %></td>
<td><%# Eval("Desc2") %></td>
<td><%# Eval("Symbol") %><%# Eval("CombUnitPrice") %></td>
<td><%# Eval("Symbol")%><%# Eval("Total") %></td>
<td><asp:DropDownList ID="lstQtyAvail" runat="server" CssClass="FTxtLst" AutoPostBack="true" Width="40px" /></td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnAllocateLine" runat="server" CssClass="FBtn" Text="Allocate" CommandName="Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SalesOrderLine") %>' OnClick="btnAllocateLine_Click" /></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Here is some of the vb code behind

```
Protected Sub btnAllocateLine_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   MsgBox("If this pops up its tells me it works and it is not at all")
   'If I try Handles btnAllocateLine.Click its tells me I need With Events
End Sub

Protected Sub Packing_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    FuncUsers_Get()
    hdnIDSO.Value = tblUsers.IDOrder
    hdnIDUser.Value = tblUsers.ID

    lvSOLGrpDelAdd.DataSource = tblDespatchA.DespatchPackSOLGrpDelAdd_Get(IDSO:=hdnIDSO.Value)
    lvSOLGrpDelAdd.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub lvSOLGrpDelAdd_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles lvSOLGrpDelAdd.ItemDataBound
    Dim lvSOLGrpDelMeth As ListView = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("lvSOLGrpDelMeth"), ListView)
    lvSOLGrpDelMeth.DataSource = tblDespatchA.DespatchPackSOLGrpDelMeth_Get(IDSO:=hdnIDSO.Value, IDGrpDelAdd:=DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "IDGrpDelAdd"))
    lvSOLGrpDelMeth.DataBind()
End Sub


Protected Sub lvSOLGrpDelMeth_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs)
    Dim lvSOL As ListView = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("lvSOL"), ListView)
    lvSOL.DataSource = tblDespatchA.DespatchPackSOL_Get(IDSO:=hdnIDSO.Value, IDGrpDelAdd:=DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "IDGrpDelAdd").ToString, IDGrpDelMeth:=DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "IDGrpDelMeth").ToString)
    lvSOL.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GOD sake. I fixed it myself. For anyone having similar problems the answer is drum roll!. Postback problems.

My Load code Binds the data, however every time you click any button it causes a Postback even though I turned AutoPostBack="False" and also ChildrenAsTriggers="false" and UpdateMode="Conditional" it still postbacks anyway. So everytime a button was clicked it was rebinding and building the parent Listview with all children whilst the button event was being fired.

Simple fix just make sure the page load event only fires when page loads not a postback. So below add the IsPostBack = False, working sample below.

```
Protected Sub Packing_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
FuncUsers_Get()
hdnIDSO.Value = tblUsers.IDOrder
hdnIDUser.Value = tblUsers.ID

If IsPostBack = False Then
lvSOLGrpDelAdd.DataSource =   tblDespatchA.DespatchPackSOLGrpDelAdd_Get(IDSO:=hdnIDSO.Value)
lvSOLGrpDelAdd.DataBind()
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Glad you could figure it out.  Been a while since doing web forms, so I completely forgot about this common issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try wiring up the event using [AddHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) in your lvSOL_RowDataBound Event Handler:

```
Protected Sub lvSOL_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs)

    Dim btnAllocateLine As Button = CType(e.Item.FindControl("btnAllocateLine"), Button)

    AddHandler btnAllocateLine.Click, AddressOf btnAllocateLine_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: First off thank you for taking your time to respond.

I tried what you said and it still didnt work both ways, wether I called the button using OnClick="btnAllocateLine_Click" or trying to add it to Handles btnAllocateLine.Click (This goes red stating with events). It has got to be something to do with the order it renders it or something. Any help will be greatly appreciated.